# facebook api . xd_proxy.php?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to post on wall using fb API, When I post a message, after share, the [link](https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f2c3dbe8c4&origin=http://localhost:8080/f1c4ddee7&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f26fe99c8&result=%7B%22post_id%22%3a%22100001210701227_250276391723830%22%7D) opens and popup remains open. Code is

```
function writeOnWall()
{ 
FB.init({ 
    appId:'292656140795961', 
    xfbml:true 
 });

 FB.ui({ 
 method: 'feed', 
 name: 'First Application'
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function postToFeed() {

// calling the API ...
var obj = {
 method: 'feed', 
 name: 'First Application'
};

function callback(response) {
  alert("Post ID: " + response['post_id']);
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

}

Try this one